# js Comparator реализация

Tags: javascript, ооп, классы

подскажите как в js можно использовать компараторы или чем их заменить.

К примеру если их нужно использовать в этой ситуации.

Есть класс Игры с полями: номер выбора, название, цена, возрастное ограничение и нужно создать компаратор к каждому из полей и организовать возможность выбора компаратора.

Comment: что в твоем понимании является компаратором? В какой ситуации ты их хочешь использовать?

Comment: @Qweriy не думаю, что по ссылке содержится ответ на вопрос. Там спрашивается конкретно о методе `sort`, а здесь человек спрашивает немного о другом. Насколько я понимаю, об альтернативах перегрузке операторов сравнения.

Comment: @smellyshovel, разве тут не про сравнение для sort? Вроде в других местах компараторы не нужны?

Comment: @Qwertiy угадывать сложно, но насколько я понял, автор вопроса хочет нечто вроде статического метода, принимающего 2 экземпляра и сравнивающего их по какому-то определенному критерию (причем критерий описывается самим автором). Ну или по крайней мере это может быть одна из реализаций. А может даже и Вы правы на самом деле. В любом случае, стоит дождаться подробностей.

Comment: @smellyshovel, так а чем этот статический метод будет отличаться от описанного в том вопросе компаратора?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не работал с компараторами, я даже не нашел информации об этом для js, само задание нужно реализовать на java, но для меня на js. Само задание и вправду достаточно мутное, вот я и обратился сюда. Вообще, можно и не использовать некие компараторы, есть они или нет в языке. Просто хотелось бы понять как такое реализовать **класс Игры с полями: номер выбора, название, цена, возрастное ограничение** и как то его выбирать.

Comment: @Apper все равно ничего не понятно. Как реализовать класс? Да просто берете и описываете его. Или вы хотите узнать, как сравнивать поля объекта? Или как изменить логику сравнения?

Comment: @Qwertiy реализация принципиально ничем, но может автора всего-то и надо было натолкнуть на мысль использовать статические методы, кто ж его знает.